# Is there a query to filter based on existence of a one-to-one relationship in django?

Tags: django

Consider the model schema:

```
class A(models.Model):
  id = models.IntegerField(...)
  ...

class B(models.Model):
  parent = models.OneToOneField(A, primary_key=True)
```

And further assume that there are more rows of A than B (e.g. not all As have details). How would I generate a query that gives me only As which have associated Bs?

I've tried A.objects.filter(b__isnull=False) which doesn't seem to work, it still returns all rows in A.

Comment: Did you try `A.objects.exclude(b__isnull=True)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried this, and it works for me:

```
A.objects.exclude(b=None)
```

or, a somewhat hackier version that relies on the (usually) integer non negative nature of primary keys

```
A.objects.filter(b__id__gte=0)
```

Now, I have a related_name, so if those don't work for you, try adding related_name.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user   = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's OneToOne, there's no manager, just the object itself. So it should be `A.B`, I think.

Answer (score 0):

What you have should work. Just verified it myself on a OneToOneField reverse relation in my own app. However, I've never tried doing that on a OneToField that's also the primary key. It's possible that that messes with the query for some reason. It's a little extra work just to test the theory, but you may want to try using a standard `AutoField` (or let Django create it automatically by removing `primary_key`) as the primary key, and see if your query works then.

Answer (score 0):

Since all B's must have A (and the reverse is not true):

```
B.objects.filter(parent__isnull=False)
```

> A one-to-one relationship. Conceptually, this is similar to a
>   ForeignKey with unique=True, but the "reverse" side of the relation
>   will directly return a single object.